# What encoding settings for BlackBerry HTML5 streaming?

Tags: html, blackberry, ffmpeg, video-codecs

For several days I've been desperately trying to get my videos stream on BlackBerry as well as the major desktop and mobile browser.
The videos are embedded in this way:

```
<video preload="auto" controls="controls">
<source src="url.mp4" type=video/mp4 />
<source src="url.ogv" type=video/ogv />
//flash fallback
</video>
```

When opening the page in the BB browser the black video frame with the controls appears but when I try to play the video the frame stays black and displays an error message: "Video portion is of an unsupported format".
Sound does play however.

By now I have tried H.264 and mpeg4 with AAC audio and both of them don't play properly on my BB (OS version 6.0).
I've been using ffmpeg to encode the files.

Comment: You didn't specify the video codecs used, only the container format. You may want to have a look at the [exact markup](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#markup) for the `<video>` tag. (Note: this may or may not be related to your problem; I simply wanted to point this out.)

Comment: I'm aware of that :) but the site gets generated via a php script that only knows the container format.
It would take quite some effort to the codecs as well. So I would refrain from doing that unless it is absolutely vital for making it work on the BB browser.

Comment: [According to HTML5test.com](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/bb06.html#head-audio), the only audio codec supported by BlackBerry OS 6 is MP3. None of the video formats [tested](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/bb06.html#head-video) are supported. (This may be a problem with the BlackBerry browser not reporting the video support correctly, however.)

Comment: @user2428118 It will be the browser's reporting. What sense does it make to support the video tag but no common video codecs?
.mp4 and and the two codecs I tried were the only formats I found that supposedly work. So I went with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A video that finally worked has the following parameters (output from ffprobe)

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
  encoder         : Lavf54.6.100
Duration: 00:02:03.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 917 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p , 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 786 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
0.00 A-V:-134874618Frame changed from size:0x0 to size:480x360
2.74 A-V:  0.070 fd=   9 aq=    7KB vq=   38KB sq=    0B f=0/0   f=0/0
```

To encode such a file use these parameters for ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "input_file.mov" -strict -2 -vcodec mpeg4 -vb 786k -acodec aac -ab 128k "output_file.mp4"
```